# Multiproperties data management with python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a tool that extracts data from a large file.
These data can be sorted according to 2 properties that are called P1 and P2 and under this form:

```
-> P1[0] : 
 |-> P2[0] : data
 |-> P2[1] : data 
 ...
-> P1[1]:
 |-> P2[0] : data
 |-> P2[1] : data 
 ...
```

In order to have a better idea of my question P1 can be considered as the time and P2 can be considered as a selection of cars that have a set of data that can be represented under the form of a pd.DataFrame and contains a set of specif data wish gives us the following structure :

```
-> at t = 0s : 
 |-> car_1 : pd.DataFrame({})
 |-> car_2 : pd.DataFrame({}) 
 ...
-> at t = 1s:
 |-> car_1 : pd.DataFrame({})
 |-> car_2 : pd.DataFrame({})
 ...
```

In my case I chose to represented the data under the form of a nested dictionary as following:

```
global_data = {0.0: {"car_1": pd.DataFrame({"data_1":[0,0,0,0],
                                            "data_1":[0,0,0,0] }),
                     "car_2": pd.DataFrame({"data_1":[0,0,0,0],
                                            "data_1":[0,0,0,0] })},
               1.0: {"car_1": pd.DataFrame({"data_1":[1,1,1,1],
                                            "data_1":[1,1,1,1] }),
                     "car_2": pd.DataFrame({"data_1":[1,1,1,1],
                                            "data_1":[1,1,1,1] })}}
```

But I don't know if there is a better solution, knowing that my objective is to display theses data in a beautiful interactive dashboard.

So my question is : Is there a better solution to manage theses type of data structure ? The thing is that even if I searched "advanced pandas usage tutorials" I don't even know the right technical words to use to find the answer to my question.

I hope that my question is clear and that you can help me.
Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

After reading the answers I think that the MultiIndex dataframe solution is the best for my need. Based on the answer of @Timeless I ended up with the following code:
We need to follow a set of indicators for a set of cars over the time. For example we need to follow the evolution of a set of indicators over the height of the car over time ( just an example). This is translated in code as following:

```
cars = [f"car_{i}" for i in range(1, 3)]
ts = np.arange(1, 3)
Time = [0, 1]
data = np.random.randint(0, 5, (len(ts)*len(cars)*len(Time), 5))
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([Time, cars, ts]).set_names(['Times', 'cars', 'Height']),
    columns=[f"Indicator_{i}" for i in range(1, 6)]
)
```

wish gives this :

```
                    Indicator_1  Indicator_2  Indicator_3  Indicator_4  Indicator_5
Times cars  Height                                                                 
0     car_1 1                 4            0            3            3            3
            2                 1            3            2            4            0
      car_2 1                 0            4            2            1            0
            2                 1            1            0            1            4
1     car_1 1                 3            0            3            0            2
            2                 3            0            1            3            3
      car_2 1                 3            0            1            1            1
            2                 0            2            4            3            3
```

In order to find specific elements in the dataframe we can use the df.query() method : `df.query("Times == 0 and cars == 'car_1'")`

So now I need to find an efficient way to display all this data in an interactive dashboard with selection bars for the time and cars I will update the post when I find a way.

Comment: A good way to manage data depends on how the it will be stored, retrieved, and used.  How do you plan on using the data once it's in whatever this new format may be?

Comment: Thanks for answer. There are two main usage. One is to quickly retrieve the set of data related to car_X at the time Y and display it in a plot using plotly for example (this is already implemented). Or a slower extraction of all data of all cars for all time-steps to be stored in .csv ? and most importantly be displayed in a dashboard that will allow to user to display the data of the wanted car at the wanted time-step. Is this clear for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is vague and the format/types of your data are not full clear (*at least for me*). Not to mention that we ignore how you receive and store the data. Though, based on the title, I would use a [*MultiIndex*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-hierarchical) with a hierarchical DataFrame to manipulate your data rather than using a nested dict.

We can read from the [*comments*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77164646/multiproperties-data-management-with-python-pandas#comment136033490_77164646) :

> *..two main usage. One is to quickly retrieve the set of data related to car_X at the time Y*

```
CAR, DATA = "car_2", ["data_1", "data_3"]
TIME_STEP = slice("2023-09-21 00:22:00", "2023-09-23 04:10:00")

query = df.xs(CAR).loc[TIME_STEP, DATA].rename_axis(None)

                     data_1  data_3
2023-09-21 02:00:00      44      91
2023-09-21 04:00:00      39      22
...                     ...     ...
2023-09-23 02:00:00      13      80
2023-09-23 04:00:00      89      99

[26 rows x 2 columns]
```

> *Or a slower extraction of all data of all cars for all time-steps to be stored in .csv ?*

```
df.to_csv("file.csv", sep=",", index=True) # feel free to adjust the parameters

# file.csv
cars,time_steps,data_1,data_2,data_3,data_4,data_5
car_1,2023-09-20 00:00:00,44,47,64,67,67
car_1,2023-09-20 02:00:00,9,83,21,36,87
car_1,2023-09-20 04:00:00,70,88,88,12,58
car_1,2023-09-20 06:00:00,65,39,87,46,88
...
```

> *.. and most importantly be displayed in a dashboard that will allow to user to display the data of the wanted car at the wanted time-step.*

```
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

fig = (
    query.plot(
        title="MultiProperties Data Management", template= "plotly",
        labels=dict(index="Time-Step", value="Values", variable="Variables"),
        width=1000, height=400)
)

fig.show();
```

[image]

Used input :

```
                           data_1  data_2  data_3  data_4  data_5
car_1 2023-09-20 00:00:00      44      47      64      67      67
      2023-09-20 02:00:00       9      83      21      36      87
      2023-09-20 04:00:00      70      88      88      12      58
      2023-09-20 06:00:00      65      39      87      46      88
      2023-09-20 08:00:00      81      37      25      77      72
...                           ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
car_9 2023-09-23 14:00:00      45       3      84      83      37
      2023-09-23 16:00:00      33      60      89       7      60
      2023-09-23 18:00:00      37      84      98      16      45
      2023-09-23 20:00:00      39      33      97      65      73
      2023-09-23 22:00:00      87      68      24       6      97

[432 rows x 5 columns]
```

---

```
np.random.seed(0)

cars = [f"car_{i}" for i in range(1, 10)] 
ts = pd.date_range("2023-09-20 00:00:00", "2023-09-23 22:15:00", freq="2H")

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0, 100, (len(ts)*len(cars), 5)),
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([cars, ts]),
    columns=[f"data_{i}" for i in range(1, 6)]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you plan on querying the dataset, I recommend you use a Data structure that you can easily query given multiple conditions. I suggest using a single DataFrame where each row is a record of the form

```
[time_x, car_y, data_list]
```

From here you can use pandas .query() function to get a new dataframe back and use that for your dashboard.

Keep your dataset as simple as possible. Given your current data structure I don't see how you could query the data you need in an efficient and simple way.

**Update**:

I was thinking something like this for a dataframe

```
data = [[0,'car_1',[0,0,0,0]],
        [0,'car_2',[0,0,0,0]],
        [1,'car_1',[0,0,0,0]],
        [1,'car_2',[0,0,0,0]]]
         
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Time','Car','Auto Data'])
df


# Time  Car     Auto Data
# 0     car_1   [0, 0, 0, 0]
# 0     car_2   [0, 0, 0, 0]
# 1     car_1   [0, 0, 0, 0]
# 1     car_2   [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Ohh I see but the 'Auto Data' are more complex than just a list this is why I need a DataFrame for it.

Comment: This just addresses the data structure general format. If you're taking further steps for optimizing query speed that's a separate matter in my opinion.

Comment: You can put whatever data you want in that column but it sounds like the number of data points varies so you don't want indivdually named columns for that. That's why I put everything in one column because it won't be an issue.

Comment: Yes this question is mostly oriented toward data structure, but the query speed optimizing will be an important question since the time steps can be about 50 and the cars can be around 1000 ( wish makes 1000 items for each time step so around 50000 dataframes to handle ) do you thinks that MultiIndex with a hierarchical DataFrame is not adapted for this use ?

Comment: Ok I see. I asked because it does not work well when I put a dataframe as Auto Data elements but perhaps i do not use it well I'll try to make it work if the MultiIndex option is not working for my case.